# How do I get a Brother dcp8070d printer working?

Tags: printing, brother

I installed ubuntu 12.04. I downloaded and installed the drivers from the Brother solutions, but the printer does not receive data for printing.

The model of the Brother laser printer is dcp8070d.

Anyone know a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. There's actually a bundle you can get from the software manager. I forget it's exact name, but it seemed obvious to me. Look for Brother Printer. I'd know for sure if I was at home, but I'm not. I'll reply later if you don't find it.

Comment: I ended up using that, and not even needing the driver from the web site. :) Hopefully you can use it the same.

Comment: Thank Frantumn. Shortly after posting the message I remembered going to the printer properties and change the make and model for a similar or lower. Not the ideal solution, but the printer is functioning as Brother DCP-8045D BR-Script3.
I think the database available on ubuntu does not consider this printer model.
If someone finds a more complete solution I thank you.
Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

When you use the drivers from the Brother solutions, make sure that **before** installing those drivers, the printer is **deleted**. When the drivers are already installed, then remove them in Synaptic and delete the printer (In Unity: Gear icon at the upper right of the screen > Printers). After deleting the printer you can install the drivers again (lpr and cupswrapper) and the printer should work now.

Comment: Thank you for the information.
I'm surprised how Ubuntu has been able to facilitate the use and installation of devices and software. It was a pleasant surprise to see that there is no need to download and install the dirvers. The system recognizes the printer and driver search solution for the user. I apologize for complicating what is increasingly simple and easy to use.
thanks